# Compiling 3 files not in the same package

Tags: java, command-line

I have 3 *.Java files. Two of the three have the statement `package com.osama.temp` and the main class does not have this statement. It only imports the 2 other classes like `import com.osama.temp.List`.

I don't know how to compile it with the Command line console .. please Help!

Comment: Have you structured the source code file locations according to the package declarations? You don't *have* to, but it helps.

Comment: the problem that i want to tell the compiler where to get the other .class files !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the directory where the main class lives create a subdirectory structure like `com/osama/temp/` and put the other 2 .java files in there. Then you should be able to compile it with `javac Main.java`

Comment: I would personally *always* specify all of the source files, rather than relying on it finding them itself. It just feels cleaner to me.

Comment: Is there another way to tell the compiler where my *.class files exists !